# How do I select the first odd/even numbered primary key in a SQL database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, indexeddb, jaydata

Let's say I have a simple table of values (almost like a key/value store). There is a primary key on the table which is indexed and auto incremented. For example here are some rows:

```
 [id]  [columnA]   [columnB]
  2     "data"    "more data"    
  3     "data"    "more data"    
  4     "data"    "more data"    
  7     "data"    "more data"
  8     "data"    "more data"
  11    "data"    "more data"
```

There might be a 1000+ values in the table.

Let's say I want to select the row containing the **first odd numbered id** in that table. In this case it should return the row `3     "data"    "more data"`.

Also how would I select the first even numbered id?

Thanks very much

Comment: Does it help you, m8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id
from table
where MOD(id, 2) = 1
order by id
limit 0, 1
```

Use mathematical function 13 % 2 = 1 (sorry, i don't know how is it in english, devide by modulo). MySQL function is [MOD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)

Answer (score 3):

This will give you all the rows having even id.

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE MOD(ID,2) = 0
```

And then on this result you can use

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY ID
```

And for odd you can use

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE MOD(ID,2) = 1
```

**If you are using SQL Server use TOP if you are using MySQL or Postgres use Limit!**

Comment: What's the difference with my answer?